# Prompt that user should enter data in only one of two cells, not both, via formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

what formula would I state if I want a cell to indicate you need to enter information into either cell D or Cell E, if they put data in D AND E "error message will appear" in cell G.

Comment: `=IF(AND(D1<>"",E1<>""),"error message will appear","")`

Comment: THIS WORKED!!! THANK YOU.

Comment: How would you state it in conditional format so that you can add a strikeout or highlight cell?

Comment: just the `AND` part.

Comment: remove the AND?

Comment: No use just the AND part in the conditional formatting rule.

Answer (score 1):

For example, in row 2, you could put the following in G2:

```
=IF(COUNTA(D2:E2)=2,"Your error message here.","")
```

This will only show the error message when something is entered in both D2 and E2.

Comment: One caveat for the OP or future readers to understand, if the values in D and E are populated by formula that return an empty string `""` then this will give false positive.  This is not a critique of this answer because based on what the OP asked this will work for the question at hand.

Comment: @ScottCraner You're right about that. I assumed since OP was talking about the user entering data in those cells, they weren't populated by formula.